# assign a tap gesture recognizer to an image inside a scroll view in Swift

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to Create a scroll view of images and tappable like Appstore screen shots,
When user touch on one image some action calls ! but here I can't find the problem that this doesn't work ! 
Notice that all of UI that i used is made by code!

```
func initScreenshots(){
    if screenShotsView.subviews.count > 0{
        screenShotsView.subviews.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview() })
    } 

    imageArray.append(UIImage.init(named: "1.jpeg")!)
    imageArray.append(UIImage.init(named: "2.jpeg")!)

    for image in imageArray {
        let index = imageArray.index(of: image)
        let imageView:UIImageView = {
            let iv = UIImageView()
            iv.image = image
            iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            return iv
        }()
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        screenShotsView.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: screenShotsView.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: screenShotsView.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 350).isActive = true
        imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 190).isActive = true
        if index == 0 {
            imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: screenShotsView.leftAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true                
        }else if( index == imageArray.count - 1 ){
            imageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: screenShotsView.rightAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
            imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: ((screenShotsView.subviews[index! - 1]).rightAnchor), constant: 10).isActive = true
        }else{
            imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: ((screenShotsView.subviews[index! - 1]).rightAnchor), constant: 10).isActive = true
        }
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }

}
```

And you can see my gesture recognizer :

```
let tapGesture:UITapGestureRecognizer = {
    let gr = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapBlurButton(_:)))
    gr.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    return gr
}()
```

My callback function is simple like this ! but it doesn't work :(

```
func tapBlurButton(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("Please Help!")
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a button and setting the background image of the button with one you want?

Comment: @OrenEdrich no but i've another button in my view that i've added this gesture recognizer but still not working :(

Comment: You do not need to add a gesture recognizer to a button. Just connect it to your .swift file. Or make an if (your button).isSelected = true{ your code}

Comment: thats true ! but I want to know why my recognizer doesn't work @OrenEdrich

Comment: Every imageView needs its own UITapGestureRecognizer.  You can't create one and use it multiple times.

Comment: @vacawama that worked ! please answer it so i confirm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every `imageView` needs its own `UITapGestureRecognizer`.  You can't create just one and use it multiple times.

Move the creation of the `UITapGestureRecognizer` into your loop and it will work.